# Evaluate $\lim_{u \to \infty} \left[100u - u\sum_{k=1}^{100}f\left(1+\frac{k}{u}\right)\right]$

Tags: calculus, limits

\begin{equation}
  f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{if  } x = 1  \\
    e^{x^{10} - 1} + (x-1)^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right), & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

---

*My solution:-*

$\lim_{u \to \infty} 100u - \lim_{u \to \infty} u\sum_{k=1}^{100}f\left(1+\frac{k}{u}\right)$

$= \lim_{u \to \infty} 100u - \left(\lim_{u \to \infty} u\right) \left(\lim_{u \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{100}f\left(1+\frac{k}{u}\right)\right)$

$= \lim_{u \to \infty} 100u - \left(\lim_{u \to \infty} u\right) \left(\sum_{k=1}^{100} \lim_{u \to \infty} f\left(1+\frac{k}{u}\right)\right)$

$= \lim_{u \to \infty} 100u - \left(\lim_{u \to \infty} u\right) \left(\sum_{k=1}^{100}1\right) \hspace{2cm} \{ \because \lim_{u \to \infty} f(1+\frac{k}{u}) = 1 \}$

$= \lim_{u \to \infty} 100u - 100\lim_{u \to \infty} u = 0$

But I saw some video solution and it wasn’t $0$. What have I done wrong

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the mistakes:

- "the limit of the sum is the sum of the limits" **only if the limits exist**.
- "the limit of the product is the product of the limits" **only if the limits exist**.

As for calculating the limit: $\def\abajo{\\[0.3cm]}$
\begin{align}
100u - u\sum_{k=1}^{100}f\left(1+\frac{k}{u}\right)
&=
100u-u\sum_{k=1}^{100}e^{(1+\frac ku)^{10}-1}+\big(\frac ku\big)^2\sin\frac uk\abajo
&=\sum_{k=1}^{100}u\Big(1-e^{(1+\frac  ku)^{10}-1}\Big)-\sum_{k=1}^{100}k\,\big(\frac ku\big)\sin\frac uk\abajo
\end{align}
Since the sine is bounded, $$\lim_{u\to\infty} \big(\frac ku\big)\sin\frac uk=0.$$ So the second sum converges to $0$. And
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{100}u\Big(1-e^{(1+\frac  ku)^{10}-1}\Big)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{100}u\Big(1-\big(1+\frac  ku\big)^{10}+o(u^{-2})\Big)\abajo
&=\sum_{k=1}^{100} {10 k}+o(u^{-1})\abajo
&\xrightarrow[u\to\infty]{}\sum_{k=1}^{100} {10 k}.
\end{align}
So
$$
\lim_{u \to \infty} \left[100u - u\sum_{k=1}^{100}f\left(1+\frac{k}{u}\right)\right]=\sum_{k=1}^{100} {10 k}=50500.
$$

Comment: Thanks for taking time and writing answer. Btw I didn’t understand the last part so I used L’Hôpital’s Rule to get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to handle the second part of @MartinArgerami's answer is to write
$$\sum_{k=1}^{100}u\Big(1-e^{(1+\frac  ku)^{10}-1}\Big)=
\sum_{k=1}^{100}k\left(\frac{1-e^{(1+\frac  ku)^{10}-1}}{\frac ku}\right)
=\sum_{k=1}^{100}k\left[\frac{g(1+\frac ku)-g(1)}{\frac ku}\right]
$$where $g(x):=-e^{x^{10}-1}$ so the expression in square brackets tends to $g'(1)=-10$ as $u\to\infty$ by the definition of the derivative. (Note the sign: the answer should be negative.)

Comment: Hmmmm Nice and yes the answer is $-50500$. Btw $g’(1) = -10$

Comment: Thanks for catching the $-10$. Fixed.